# Converting facebook pixel event to app event in hybrid mobile app

Tags: facebook-pixel, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am trying to send App Events from Hybrid mobile app(cordova). Through Facebook Pixel event can be sent but as stated by this [blog](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/v2/2018/07/31/hybrid-web-apps/) - "Sending App Events in the context of a mobile application can provide a number of advantages over sending pixel events".

Events for hybrid mobile apps as per this facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/hybrid-app-events) mentions it is possible to convert Facebook Pixel event into App Events. The total code change required in your application is two lines (one native, one web).

For web
fbq('init', );
fbq('set', 'mobileBridge', , );

For Native:
android:
AppEventsLogger.augmentWebView(, )

ios:
[FBSDKAppEvents augmentHybridWKWebView:];

So my question is where to updated this native part code in case of android and ios in cordova app?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I have been stuck with this issue for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/hybrid-app-events/

It states (the full statement): "When you augment a webview from iOS or Android, we inject a window level object called fbmq_. The Pixel, when set up to look for a mobile bridge, finds this window level fbmq object each time an fbq call is made."

Let`s brake it down:"**When you augment** a webview from iOS or Android..."

Android:

```
AppEventsLogger.augmentWebView(<YOUR_WEBVIEW_OBJECT>, <YOUR_ANDROID_CONTEXT>)
```

iOS:

```
[FBSDKAppEvents augmentHybridWKWebView:<YOUR_WK_WEB_VIEW_OBJECT>];
```

"...we inject a window level object called fbmq_. The Pixel, **when set up to look for a mobile bridge**, finds this window level fbmq object each time an fbq call is made.""

Setup should look something like this:

```
 fbq('init', '');
    if (window.cordova){
      fbq('set', 'mobileBridge', '', '');
}
```

Disclaimer: This is not tested and is an only theoretical implementation based on the documentation that Facebook provides.

Comment: but the question remains: where to put the android/ios code?

Comment: Inside the app. It will augment the WebView component and will create a bridge between WebView and Native side of the app.

Comment: of course there, but as a Javascript developer using capacitorJS, I'm completely avulse to native programming, then I need to know exactly what piece of code to inject and in what module of the natives apps...

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps!

Download FB connect Cordova Plugin from here : https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect (This plugin will help you to track your hybrid app events)

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook-connect --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication" --variable FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS="true"

The above plugin auto enables "AppEventsLogger.augmentWebView(<YOUR_WEBVIEW_OBJECT>, <YOUR_ANDROID_CONTEXT>)"

However if for some reason it does not work then

Navivate to:: platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\facebook\ConnectPlugin.java

[code snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f6ZJ.png)